# How to convert typescript project to node package

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-declarations

I have an older typescript project that exports a lot of functions and interfaces in multiple files.  Dependent packages pulled in those exports by linking directly to the file in the directory.

I am trying to convert the dependency to a true npm package, with an index.js and index.d.js, but struggling with how.  I don't know what those two files should look like.

For example, I need to export both a type HttpHandler and an implementation httpHandler

For this package, there is no default.

Examples?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to accomplish this: https://itnext.io/step-by-step-building-and-publishing-an-npm-typescript-package-44fe7164964c

Comment: except; all the examples show putting the code in index.js and the types in index.d.ts.  I already have code in multiple files like src/a.ts and src/b.ts.  I don't know how to make them visible or as a module

Comment: Create a `index.ts` file, then add `export * from './src/a';` and `export * from './src/b';`.

Comment: Paul, you want to put that in an answer, because you nailed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example library `@ed4becky/acme`.  The library's source code is in the `src` directory, and a fake consumer (`fake-external-consumer.ts`).  In a real world example, `fake-exernal-consumer.ts` would be in its own repo/project, I just kept it outside the `src` for as a visual indictor and for simplicity purposes.  In the example you can see how I created the library `@ed4becky/acme`, and how it's imported `import { A, B } from @ed4becky/acme`.  I'm able to import from the library because class A and B are exported in `src/index.ts`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-gauss-b8zjk

Comment: I had to make one correction to the existing code to get this work.  The method I was using as mu guinea pig was defined "const a1 = "  then at the bottom export default a1;   I changed it to export const a1 and removed the default.  Thanks for quick response